# UITextField randomly reusing text in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm having some issues with my table that has `UITextFields` in each cell.  I notice text is still getting reused randomly in the wrong cells even though I seem to be saving it correctly.

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == temperatureTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.temperatureTextField.text forKey:@"temperature"];
    }
    else if (textField == pulseTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.temperatureTextField.text forKey:@"pulse"];
    }
    else if (textField == respiratoryRateTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.temperatureTextField.text forKey:@"respiratory_rate"];
    }
}
```

CellForRowAtIndex:

```
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
                cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];
                self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField;
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
                cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"pulse"];
                self.pulseTextField = cell.textField;
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Respiratory Rate";
                cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"respiratory_rate"];
                self.respiratoryRateTextField = cell.textField;
                break;
```

Comment: what is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: The bottom method is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like simple typos in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` where you are always saving the value from `temperatureTextField`. Change your code to:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == temperatureTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.temperatureTextField.text forKey:@"temperature"];
    }
    else if (textField == pulseTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.pulseTextField.text forKey:@"pulse"];
    }
    else if (textField == respiratoryRateTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.respiratoryRateTextField.text forKey:@"respiratory_rate"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this was the problem, but the issue is still happening, lets say I enter text in a cell, then scroll down, enter text in another, then the first cell's text is sometimes gone.

Comment: with the code you posted I can't tell, but looks like you are overwriting old values in your data source (`vitalsDictionary`) as you edit cells. This means any old cells of that type will get the latest change for that key. To fix this you need a data source that allows multiple entries for each type in a structured way. Probably an NSArray of NSDictionaries. Or if you want to persist your changes look into Core Data.

Comment: Hmm, everything looks right.  Can I send you a copy of the project if you could quickly take a look at it? Its very simple.

Comment: sorry, I don't have the time to dig into the whole project. My original answer was definitely a bug in the code you posted. Beyond that, if you only are storing 3 values in `vitalsDictionary` and `vitalsDictionary` is the data source for your table (i.e. where you get the cell values from in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` then you will only see those three values in your cells, no matter how many cells you have. Is that the issue?

Comment: There are a total of 10 cells, and 10 keys in `vitalDictionary`.  I can only fit like 6 on the screen so if I enter text in all of them, then scroll down, and then scroll back up, they will either be empty or have no data in it.

Comment: when you scroll down and back up the cells are reloaded, meaning `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called again for those cells. How about you enter a new question and post your code in this method along with how you are setting the values for all of those keys. The code in this question doesn't show all of that. Ok, I have the holiday spirit. If you share your project with me on github I'll take a quick look. Same username.

Comment: I'd rather not. I added an answer on your other question. You're getting good advice and getting closer to fixing your app.