# UITextField reusing text in UITextField randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

This is an extension of this question here:  [UITextField randomly reusing text in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250354/uitextfield-randomly-reusing-text-in-tableview/8250414#8250414)

I'm having some issues with my table that has UITextFields in each cell. I notice text is still getting reused randomly in the wrong cells even though I seem to be saving it correctly.

```
 else if (tableView == self.vitalsTableView)
    {
        if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
            CellIdentifier = @"bloodPressureCell";
            BloodPressureTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.textField1.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"blood_pressure_1"];
            cell.textField2.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"blood_pressure_2"];
            self.bloodPressureTextField1 = cell.textField1;
            self.bloodPressureTextField2 = cell.textField2;
            return cell;
        }
        else if ([indexPath row] == 9){
            CellIdentifier = @"statusCell";
            SmokingStatusTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            return cell;
        }
        else if ([indexPath row] == 10){
            CellIdentifier = @"vitalsCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            return cell;
        }
        else{
            CellIdentifier = @"textCell";
            VitalsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];
                    self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"pulse"];
                    self.pulseTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Respiratory Rate";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"respiratory_rate"];
                    self.respiratoryRateTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Oxygen Saturation";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"oxygen_saturation"];
                    self.oxygenSaturationTextField = cell.textField;;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Height";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"height"];
                    self.heightTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Weight";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"weight"];
                    self.weightTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"BMI";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"bmi"];
                    self.bmiTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pain (1-10)";
                    cell.textField.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"pain"];
                    self.painTextField = cell.textField;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return cell;
        }

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == temperatureTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.temperatureTextField.text forKey:@"temperature"];
    }
    else if (textField == pulseTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.pulseTextField.text forKey:@"pulse"];
    }
    else if (textField == respiratoryRateTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.respiratoryRateTextField.text forKey:@"respiratory_rate"];
    }
    else if (textField == oxygenSaturationTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.oxygenSaturationTextField.text forKey:@"oxygen_saturation"];
    }
    else if (textField == heightTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.heightTextField.text forKey:@"height"];
    }
    else if (textField == weightTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.weightTextField.text forKey:@"weight"];
    }
    else if (textField == bmiTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.bmiTextField.text forKey:@"bmi"];
    }
    else if (textField == painTextField){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.painTextField.text forKey:@"pain"];
    }
    else if (textField == bloodPressureTextField1){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.bloodPressureTextField1.text forKey:@"blood_pressure_1"];
    }
    else if (textField == bloodPressureTextField2){
        [self.vitalsDictionary setObject:self.bloodPressureTextField2.text forKey:@"blood_pressure_2"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check by doing `textField == pulseTextField`, because `UITableview` will reuse cells in a unpredictable manner as long as the reuse identifiers match. You are storing a reference to a text field, but when you scroll up and down, that cell may get assigned a different index. So, you may end up with duplicate reference to the same text field, since some cells may be off-screen with outdated duplicate reference.

Comment: One option is to utilize `tag`, a `UIView` property. That way `UITextField` will have a single tag attached to it, so you can identify what it is used for. Note that `tag` is just `NSInteger`, so you should probably declare some constants first.

Comment: That sounds perfect, can you help me with this as I haven't used constants before?  I have 11 cells as shown in the example code.  Im thinking instead of setting `self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField;`,  would do `self.temperatureTextField.tag = 1` or something similar

Comment: @Barum is correct, you should use tags to access your textFields. Use  `cell.textField.tag = 1;` when creating a cell. make sure you use a unique integer for each type of textField possible within the cell. In `textFieldDidEndEditing:` use `if (textField.tag == TAG_VALUE)` to check for a specific type of textField. I see another issue which I'll put in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Barum's correct answer with regard to how you are accessing text fields you also have a problem creating cells. You are dequeuing cached cells but I don't see your code creating a new cell if dequeuing returns nil. You need to do the following:

```
else if (tableView == self.vitalsTableView) {
    if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
        CellIdentifier = @"bloodPressureCell";
        BloodPressureTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            // create cell if nothing dequeued
            cell = [[BloodPressureTableViewCell alloc] init...]; // use an appropriate initializer
            cell.textField1.tag = MyTextFieldTagBloodPressure1;
            cell.textField2.tag = MyTextFieldTagBloodPressure2; 
        }
        // configure the cell
        cell.textField1.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"blood_pressure_1"];
        cell.textField2.text = [self.vitalsDictionary objectForKey:@"blood_pressure_2"];
        return cell;
    }
    // do the same for all cell types
```

Note: the example above assumes you define an enum for your tag values. I recommend this as it makes the code more readable and you won't have to remember which integer is which field type.